# WLM Contacts Failed To Import

Tags: windows, email, windows-live-mail

Using Windows 7 Pro.  Testing backup for WLM Contacts.  I exported to a CSV file.  Trying to Import, I get Import in Progress, with no movement in the progress bar.  Waited 20 minutes, still no response.  Task manager shows "Running".

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem before, my problem is because I tried to save it in the c:\ which is consider a write protected dir along with c:\windows. Notice that I cannot even create empty text file in certain dir. changing the path to the usual document folder solved my problem. but not sure if yours is the same problem as mine.